# Why can't we use angular-fire2 package for firebase with Nativescript Angular app

Tags: firebase, nativescript

If nativescript is using javascript engine behind the scene. If I use angular for nativescript development, shouldn't I be able to use angular-fire2 for firebase.

if I could code sharing would be much better with Web and Mob App.

Answer (score -1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46088932/6408287 contains the answer you are looking for. In short - NativeScript does not implement the node.js modules specification.

Angular-fire2 is made to run inside node.js, whereas mobile firebase sdks are made to run on mobile platforms. Efficiently. Hence the difference in APIs.

Even if you were to somehow run angular-fire2 on NativeScript, chances are it wouldn't execute as well as the mobile sdks would.

Comment: Thank you..!!   if angularfire2 is just a js package which run on browser, shouldn't it run on nativescript run time considering that it has js runtime.

Comment: angular-fire2 is expected to run in a browser/server. Mobile devices have different specifications, more limitations, they work differently. Mobile SDKs are also optimized and made to work with the device's operating system and application lifecycle events. The same does not apply to node.js backends.

Comment: And please note the part with the link where I explicitly explain why most node.js npm packages can't run inside the nativescript runtimes.