# Fireloop.io chat app with nativescript

Tags: socket.io, angular2-nativescript, loopback, fireloop

I loved with loopback. But I am new with fireloop. fireloop working fine with angular 4 webapp client but when I try to use fireloop with nativeapp client (nativescript) its SDK only work for REST API. its Real-time feature not working.

debug logs only show 'Creating a new connection with: '
for example:

```
Creating a new connection with: http://192.123.1.13:3000
```

only this just logging in console.

I need some guide to settings up fireloop real-time feature with nativeapp.

sorry for my language.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with the websocket api. I presume for the real time you might actually be using that. Its is related to a question I asked earlier regarding angularfire2 and nativescript.

Here is one response: angular-fire2 is expected to run in a browser/server. Mobile devices have different specifications, more limitations, they work differently. Mobile SDKs are also optimized and made to work with the device's operating system and application lifecycle events. The same does not apply to node.js backends.

[angular fire2 and nativescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088025/why-cant-we-use-angular-fire2-package-for-firebase-with-nativescript-angular-ap)

Comment: thanks for reply. But I want to use http://fireloop.io SDK because It provides proper way to bind model with client side. otherwise it manage by my self.